# Charging of a capacitor

Tags: electric-circuits, charge, capacitance, batteries

while charging the plates of a parallel plate capacitor by a battery,i have seen in books that the positive charges remain only on the right side of the first plate what is connected to the positive terminal of the battery and negative charges only on the left side of the plate connected to the negative terminal of the battery,why the charges do not remain on both sides in both the plates.

Comment: It's a little hard to understand what you mean... If you add some drawing to clarify how the circuit looks like, people will be able to help you.

Comment: If you are able please include such an image from one of books.

Answer (score 0):

Let's just assume that there do exist charges on both sides of the plate. In such a situation, the plate with positive charges will have some charges on the side facing the other plate, and some charges on the other side and the same story for the negatively charged plate. The positive charges on the side facing out will face repulsion from the positive charges on the other side of the same plate and attraction from the negative charges on the other plate.

If you do the math now, the positive charges on the side facing out will experience greater attraction than repulsion. So they will flow towards the side facing the negative plate. And the same story goes for the negatively charged plate.

Only when all the charges are at the inner sides of the plates of the capacitor will there be an equilibrium.

Answer (score -1):

Does the book state that excess charge goes to the outside of the two plates? Perhaps it is drawn like that for convenience. Opposite charges attract, so excess charge is drawn to the inside.